# Julia: in @formula how I specifyc all columns except target?

Tags: julia

In R

```
glm(target ~., data=data)
```

Will fit a model using all columns of data except target.

How do I achieve the same in Julia using the `@formula` macro?

```
glm(@formula(target ~ .), data)
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `data` is a data frame from DataFrames.jl for simplicity. Here is an example how to do it:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand(6, 5))
6×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1         │ x2        │ x3       │ x4       │ x5        │
│     │ Float64    │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.774058   │ 0.248908  │ 0.926771 │ 0.544818 │ 0.159493  │
│ 2   │ 0.549339   │ 0.60138   │ 0.711105 │ 0.916472 │ 0.703073  │
│ 3   │ 0.455965   │ 0.0912193 │ 0.178479 │ 0.472463 │ 0.0229811 │
│ 4   │ 0.0242736  │ 0.0131428 │ 0.833545 │ 0.232273 │ 0.170568  │
│ 5   │ 0.00796519 │ 0.0655102 │ 0.326123 │ 0.61535  │ 0.148247  │
│ 6   │ 0.653029   │ 0.695704  │ 0.817001 │ 0.11801  │ 0.459253  │

julia> lm(term(:x1) ~ sum(term.([1; names(df, Not(:x1))])), df)
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

x1 ~ 1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5

Coefficients:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
              Estimate  Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  -0.24995     0.358235  -0.697725    0.6122   -4.80176    4.30186
x2            2.12158     0.784308   2.70504     0.2254   -7.84399   12.0872
x3            0.483761    0.411032   1.17694     0.4484   -4.73889    5.70641
x4            0.747987    0.48225    1.55104     0.3646   -5.37958    6.87555
x5           -2.21183     1.03313   -2.14091     0.2782  -15.339     10.9153
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

However, in general I try to avoid doing this (i.e. using a synonym of `.`) as it is usually safer to explicitly specify which variables you want to have in your model. Note that this is really easy in the pattern I show as the only thing you need to do is to replace `names(df, Not(:x1))` by a list of variables you want to include, which e.g. could be

```
names(df, All(r"first_type_of_predictors", r"second_type_of_predictors")))
```

so as you can see it is really flexible.